# Google api key Ilegal operatioan

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the api key for google maps but I tried this line and i got this error

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\KHALED\.android -storepass android -keypass android
Illegal option:  androiddebugkey
Key and Certificate Management Tool
Commands:
 -certreq            Generates a certificate request
 -changealias        Changes an entry's alias
 -delete             Deletes an entry
 -exportcert         Exports certificate
 -genkeypair         Generates a key pair
 -genseckey          Generates a secret key
 -gencert            Generates certificate from a certificate request
 -importcert         Imports a certificate or a certificate chain
 -importkeystore     Imports one or all entries from another keystore
 -keypasswd          Changes the key password of an entry
 -list               Lists entries in a keystore
 -printcert          Prints the content of a certificate
 -printcertreq       Prints the content of a certificate request
 -printcrl           Prints the content of a CRL file
 -storepasswd        Changes the store password of a keystore
Use "keytool -command_name -help" for usage of command_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add

```
-list -alias
```

between "keytool" and "androiddebugkey" in your command line - i.e.:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\KHALED\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: It gives me this error keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\KHALE
D\.android

Comment: Check whether you have a directory called "C:\Users\KHALED\.android" if you do then check there is a file called debug.keystore there.  There was a minor error in the command above as I took your command line, but missed the fact you didn't specify the debug.keystore file. I've edited the command in this answer, so if the debug.keystore file exists you should be able to paste the command above onto your command line.